# PostgreSQL Accentuation | Entity Framework | NpgsqlTsVector | Unaccent

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I'm writing a database query method and I have two challenges:

1. **Full-text search** (e.g., finding "WIRELESS BLUE MOUSE" when typing "BLUE MOUSE").
   This issue was resolved using Postgre's NpgsqlTsVector. An attribute was created in the class and mapped to the database, creating a 'Matches' column and managing the responsible index.
2. **Searching while ignoring accents** (e.g., searching for "JOSE" should return both "JOSE" and "JOSÉ").

I can solve this problem using Postgres' Unaccent extension; however, it seems that it doesn't work together with NpgsqlTsVector."

e.g. :

```cs
queryable = queryable .Where(x => x.Name.Matches(fiter));
queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.DescricaoSaida.Contains(EF.Functions.Unaccent(fitro)));
```

The language is set to "portuguese"

I'm trying to make both functionalities work together.

EDIT: The generated query is:

```
SELECT 
  fields...
FROM 
  "Table..." AS p 
WHERE 
  p."EmpresaId" = @__query_EmpresaId_0 
  AND p."Ativo" 
  AND (
    p."Pesquisa" @@ plainto_tsquery(@__8__locals1_fitro_1) 
    OR unaccent(@__ToUpper_3) = '' 
    OR strpos(
      unaccent(p."DescricaoSaida"), 
      unaccent(@__ToUpper_3)
    ) > 0 
    OR (
      (p."Sku" IS NOT NULL) 
      AND (
        unaccent(@__ToUpper_3) = '' 
        OR strpos(
          p."Sku", 
          unaccent(@__ToUpper_3)
        ) > 0
      )
    )
  ) 
ORDER BY 
  p."Id" DESC
```

Comment: Could you show us the SQL that is generated by your code?

Comment: @FrankHeikens sure:

SELECT fields... FROM "Table..." AS p
      WHERE p."EmpresaId" = @__query_EmpresaId_0 AND p."Ativo" AND (p."Pesquisa" @@ plainto_tsquery(@__8__locals1_fitro_1) OR unaccent(@__ToUpper_3) = '' OR strpos(unaccent(p."DescricaoSaida"), unaccent(@__ToUpper_3)) > 0 OR ((p."Sku" IS NOT NULL) AND (unaccent(@__ToUpper_3) = '' OR strpos(p."Sku", unaccent(@__ToUpper_3)) > 0)))
      ORDER BY p."Id" DESC

the query it's working now, but i think tha'ts not the best practice, because i'm concatening matches() || contains () 
i was wondering if collation isn't the best way...

Comment: Are you sure postgres is the right tool for that matter?